# What are hardware requirements to run a small mining pool?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-hardware, mining-pool-setup, raspberry-pi

Im planning on setting up a small Monero or DigitalNote minig pool just for fun. If for example, 10 people connect to that pool, what would be the hardware requirements for it (CPU, RAM and storage)? Could I run it on a Raspberry Pi 3? Would it somehow be profitable?

I have researched a bit and it looks like Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is the best choice for the server software. The raspberry pi reaches the hardwae requirements, but is it enough?

Comment: You've asked a number of questions here. I'll tackle the RP3 - no, at this time there aren't any coins you can CPU mine profitably with the device. The RP3 cost is approximately $6 @ 0.15kW/h per annum. That said, it is capable of mining so you can think of it as a lottery chance for a reward (i.e. $6 lottery "ticket" for multiple chances per year). The `chance` is remarkably bad, but it is greater than zero.

Comment: I actually intended to use the RP3 as a server only. The computers connected to it would do the mining. Is that possible?

Comment: I can't say from experience. It may be a bit of a "risk" as the SSDs in PI3s can corrupt from abnormal shutdowns more than we'd like...but conceptually I'd say yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a pool requires a pretty reliable machine. Pi's are fun, but they don't fit the bill. Spend a few bucks a month on a VPS with 2GB of RAM at least and enough disk space to house the Monero blockchain (to run the full-node daemon), and you'll reliably be able to keep a pool up. Who knows, make it public and others might use it too!

Also, wouldn't recommend running any full-node on a home connection as the bandwidth usage is very noticeable. Maybe I'm just saying that because of my wonderful Australian internet connection. (ha.)

Comment: If I had to build my own server, what CPU, RAM, and storage specs should it have?

Comment: My point is you shouldn't build your own server. Instead you should get a VPS that is hosted on another machine in a datacentre somewhere. It's much more reliable and you don't have to worry about a physical machine using electricity and bandwidth in your house. Plus setting up the routing so public users of the internet can connect to it is painful.

Answer (score 2):

I use a server at home and it is an old Power Edge 2950 (2 x duel quad core Xeons and 32gb RAM).  I am running UBUNTU 14.04 LTS and it seems to run the daemon, wallet, and front end via Apache2 pretty well. I haven't had a bunch of traffic on it yet because it is still in the testing phase and it is like pulling teeth finding miners to connect and hash to test everything out but it seems stable.  I would think a quad core or better processor and at least 8 gb of RAM would be a pretty minimum requirement.  Anything else would be a bonus unless you are planning on having hundreds/thousands connect in which case a VPS or upgrading to a newer hardware setip (perhaps with a Gb switch) would be warranted.